# Não estou conseguindo encontrar os índices dos maiores numero

Tags: c

Bom estou fazendo um programa que precisa saber os índices dos maiores valores no vetor, porém não estou conseguindo, o código que eu tentei.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double vetor[10];
  int indice[10], c = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    scanf("%lf", &vetor[i]);
  }
  double maior = vetor[0];
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     if(vetor[i] > maior)
     {
        maior = vetor[i];
        indice[c] = i + 1;
        c++;
     }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
  {
     printf("%d ", indice[i]);
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: O seu objetivo é achar o índice apenas do maior numero ? Se sim porque motivo `indice` é um vetor com 10 posições ?

Comment: Não é só do maior número, e sim dos maiores números do vetor

Comment: Dos maiores ? Mas quantos ? Pelo seu exemplo parecem ser todos os `10`, o que não faria muito sentido. Melhor será tentar clarificar e dar um exemplo de números de entrada e resultado de saída.

Comment: números
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
índices dos maiores valores
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Então o `0` é o primeiro indice a aparecer, mas na posição `0` está o menor valor. Não há por ai uma confusão ?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve iniciar a variável `maior` com um valor diferente do que já está no vetor, digamos por exemplo -DBL_MAX (definido em float.h). Dessa forma você sabe que qualquer coisa que vier será maior (provavelmente).

Além disso quando for armazenar o índice não precisa somar 1 faça:

```
indice[c] = i;
```